# Get the highest occurrence between 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have 2 columns, called decision1 and decision2.

I want to compare them in order to get the highest occurrence between the 2, so I either get the highest occurrence in decision1 or decision2, according to the greatest one. So far my attempts led to this, but with no success since I just get the highest occurrence in EACH column and not combined

```
 # weightage option
if args['weightage'] == "yes":
    attr1 = data['decision'].value_counts().idxmax  #highest occurrence in decision
    attr2 = data['decision2'].value_counts().idxmax #highest occurrence in decision2
    heaviest_attribute = data.groupby(['decision','decision2']).size()
```

Ideally I would just need to use some kind of `max()` function between `attr1` and `attr2` but I don't know how to handle this.

For example, given this table

[image]

I want to compare decision1 and decision2 columns as if they were one column, and the expected output, in this case, would be 'Yes', because it's the most recurrent value.

Comment: Do you think `data.groupby(['decision','decision2']).size().idxmax` ?

Comment: Can you add some data smaple and expected output?

Comment: Sample input output is much appreciated to better understand your problem

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks, I added a sample table as reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) and select first value by position with [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
a = df[['decision','decision 2']].melt()['value'].mode().iat[0]
```

Or reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
a = df[['decision','decision 2']].stack().mode().iat[0]
```

---

```
print (a)
Yes
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df[['decision','decision 2']].melt()['value'])
0        Yes
1      Maybe
2        Yes
3      Maybe
4        Yes
5         No
6         No
7    Perhaps
8    Perhaps
9     unsure
Name: value, dtype: object
```

```
print (df[['decision','decision 2']].stack())
0  decision          Yes
   decision 2         No
1  decision        Maybe
   decision 2         No
2  decision          Yes
   decision 2    Perhaps
3  decision        Maybe
   decision 2    Perhaps
4  decision          Yes
   decision 2     unsure
dtype: object
```

EDIT:

```
s = df.eq(a).any()

col = s.index[s][0]
print (col)
decision
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm (especially `a = df[['decision','decision 2']].stack().mode().iat[0]`). One bonus question though: by getting this value, assuming each column has its own values so in our case 'Yes' will always be in decision, and never in decision2, can we retrieve the column name by using the value?

Comment: @AndreRetroPie - I think I understand, answer was edited.

Comment: Thanks sir, you're my hero

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution.

Its best to convert the content into a list and finding max occurance in list is simple.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'decision': ['yes', 'maybe', 'yes', 'maybe', 'yes'], 
               'decision 2': ['No', 'No', 'Perhaps', 'Perhaps', 'unsure']
            })
a = list(data['decision'])+list(data['decision 2'])
a = max(set(a), key=a.count)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
yes
```

Comment: This is returning "yes" because the `max` function takes the last alphabetical letters as the greatest value. Try `max(['yes','yes','maybe', 'z'])` and you'll see the issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've updated my code now. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there exist a much more elegant solution...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'decision': ['Yes', 'Maybe', 'Yes', 'Maybe', 'Yes'], 
                   'decision 2': ['No', 'No', 'Perhaps', 'Perhaps', 'unsure']})

d1 = dict(df.groupby('decision').count().loc[:, 'decision 2'])
d2 = dict(df.groupby('decision 2').count().loc[:, 'decision'])

d1.update(d2)

max(d1, key=d1.get)
```